# Is there a public key stream cipher encryption?

Tags: python, encryption, public-key-encryption

I have a program that regularly appends small pieces (say 8 bytes) of sensitive data to a number of logfiles. I would like this data to be encrypted. I want the program to start automatically at boot time, so I don't want to type a password at program start. I also don't want it to store a password somewhere, since that would almost defeat the purpose of encryption.

For these reasons, it seems to me that public key encryption would be a good choice. The program knows my public key, but my private key is password protected somewhere else.

So far, so good. But when I try to use PyCrypto to RSA (or ElGamal)-encrypt a small 5-byte string, the output explodes to 128 bytes. My logfiles are large enough as it is... On the other hand, when I try a symmetric crypto, like Blowfish, the output string is just as large as the input string.

So, my question is: Is there a reasonably secure public key encryption algorithm where I can encrypt data 8 bytes at a time and don't have it blow up? (I guess a factor of 2 would be OK). I think what I want is a public key stream cipher.

If there is not such a thing, I think I will just give up and use a symmetric crypto and give the password manually on startup.

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing; there's a tendency to use session keys (i.e. symmetric cypher keys derived from something protected by an asymmetric cypher) in things like SSL, but I don't know how to make that work in your case (the communication is one-way…)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically this is solved in the way that the program creates some (real) random numbers which are used as a secret key to a symmetric encryption algorithm.

In you program you have to do something like:

1. Generate some real random data (maybe use /dev/random) as a secret key.
2. Encrypt the secret key with the public key algorithm.
3. Use the secret key for some other symmetric algorithm.

To decrypt this,

1. Use the private key to decrypt the secret key.
2. Use the secret key and the symmetric algorithm to decrypt the data.

You might want to get some random data (e.g. >=256bit) for a 'good' key.

Comment: This sounds like the way to go. (IANAC)

Comment: Perhaps you are right, but I don't really see the point. Each time at start up, I will have to give the private key, so it can retrieve its old password. What would be the benefit compared to just giving a password for a symmetric algorithm at start up?

Comment: The idea is to use the public key for encryption.  When decrypting you have to use the private key. (Maybe I miss a requirement?)

Comment: Maybe I am missing something. You generate a password and use a public key to store it encrypted somewhere. But each time the program is started, it cannot just generate a new key, or the logs will be a hopeless mess. So it will have to decrypt the file with the password. To do this, it will need my private key. My private key will either not be stored on the same computer, or it will be password protected. Either way it is no easier than to just supply it with my symmetric password. Your approach would only be better if the program ran just once. Like in an SSL connection.

Comment: @Gurgeh "Each time at start up, I will have to give the private key" -No, you generate a new random key, and somehow keep track of what data has been encrypted with which key.

Comment: @JanneKarila I realized that was a possibility, but it just seemed so messy. I will have up to a hundred different log files, so I will have to keep track of which key belongs to which section in each file. But now that you made me think about it, I understand that it is certainly doable.

Comment: @Gurgeh You could consider using a database instead of all those plain files.

Comment: @JanneKarila Yeah, I am considering MySQL or SQLite, but it seems to be quite a lot of overhead (I am mainly worried about space) compared to a plain file, where I know all entries are read-only and can be packed tightly. Also, then this public key scheme would not work.

Comment: password is the wrong word to use. The correct word or phrase is "symmetric key".

Comment: @GregS just read your comment after editing it to "secret key", which I presume would also gain your approval (symmetric key and symmetric cipher is too repetative in my taste)

Comment: @Gurgeh: Keeping track of the keys used isn't too hard if you allow your log files to contain a special "key change" record, that gives the (encrypted) symmetric key for the following log records.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to do something like SSL does: exchange a key using public key encryption, then use symmetric encryption. Asymmetric encryption is very inefficient in terms of performance, and should not be used for such stuff.

Comment: "exchange a key" with whom? There is just one computer involved. Your answer seems similar to @Andreas Florath's, but I don't see why public key encryption needs to be involved if am just going to use symmetric encryption in the end?

Comment: how will you avoid selecting a password? Whatever the reader will be, whether it is a client or whatever, if the password needs to be interchanged between the writer and the reader in a way that it can be sniffed or intercepted, you need to encrypt it. if you don't need this, just encrypt your logs with a symmetric cipher.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what Gurgeh has in mind, but I think he wants to avoid using a password for the logger to write to the encrypted log files.  If he uses public-key cryptography, he can leave a public key on the system that will be used to encrypt the logs, but cannot be used to decrypt.  He keeps his private key secret and uses it to decrypt the logs when he needs to.  How is any password necessary here?

Comment: @BrendanWood, that is exactly what I want.

Comment: the reason to avoid public key cryptography here is the performance overhead. if the logs are not written frequently it's fine, but doing it constantly will kill his logger's performance. Symmetric encryption should be 1000 to 10000 times faster.